# iOS/Android app as browser only

Tags: android, ios, browser

My web application run's nicely on every smartphone. An additional native iOS/Android app would have the advantage of being available over the app stores and more visible to users. But I find it unnecessary work to do everything from scratch in all the development environments.

Instead I could make an app that just implements a web browser and just shows the website. Does someone know if this is allowed by Apple/Google at all? I have heard that at least Microsoft seems to have nothing against it in their Windows Phone market.

Thanks

Comment: Apple doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

@ quape, apple will reject the application made with the idea you are thinking so it will be of no use to move in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will simply reject the application for lack of functionality...
I have absolutely no idea about Google's policy on that question.